# what would happen if you use two equals rather than only one in your execution block after an if conditional in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am still learning, so I'm sorry if my question is not well formatted.

I was trying to write a function to insert a word to a string in a specified position, however I made a mistake which is writing two equal signs `==` rather than one in the execution block and this resulted in wrong output when tested.

However, I already know that the execution of code after `if`/`else` needs to not be boolean and I noticed this typo and I corrected it by removing one equal sign and the function worked perfectly fine but I was just left wondering why have I never questioned the significance of strictly having one equal sign when executing code after if conditionals.

so here is the wrong code:

```
function insert(original,to_insert,position){ 
    if (to_insert == "undefined" && position == undefined){return original;}
    else if (position == undefined){position == 0}

    var x = original.slice(0,position); 

    var y = original.slice(position); 

    console.log(x + to_insert + y);
}

insert('We are doing some exercises.','JavaScript '); 
//Wrong output >>>> "We are doing some exercises.JavaScript We are doing some exercises."

insert('We are doing some exercises.','JavaScript ', 18);
//correct output>>>>  "We are doing some JavaScript exercises."
```

and here is the correct code:

```
function insert(original,to_insert,position){ 
    if (to_insert == "undefined" && position == undefined){return original;}
    else if (position == undefined){position = 0}

    var x = original.slice(0,position); 

    var y = original.slice(position); 

    console.log(x + to_insert + y);
}

insert('We are doing some exercises.','JavaScript '); 
//correct output >>>> JavaScript We are doing some exercises."

insert('We are doing some exercises.','JavaScript ', 18);
//correct output>>>>  "We are doing some JavaScript exercises."
```

would you please explain what happens inside my wrong code, like what causes the function to not run properly when booleans were used, obviously the function runs once at a time, so what difference would an absolute value of position make compared to a variable value of position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `position == 0` is wrong in your case, because is evaluating equality, not assigning, like `position = 0`

Comment: thanks alot Santiago

Comment: Downvoters, would you please comment what you disliked in my question so I can try to improve the quality of my questions later, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if (position == undefined){position == 0}`

In your wrong code, `position` remains `undefined` since you did not do an assignment, you simply checked if `position` (which is `undefined`) is equal to  `0`

So, when you did `var x = original.slice(0,position);` `slice()` simply ignored the 2nd argument, which in this case is `undefined` and sliced from start to end, which is the default behaviour in case the 2nd argument is not used.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

> The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.
>
> `str.slice(beginSlice[, endSlice])`
>
> **endSlice**
>
> Optional. The zero-based index at which to end extraction. **If omitted, slice() extracts to the end of the string.** If negative, it is treated as sourceLength + endSlice where sourceLength is the length of the string (for example, if endSlice is -3 it is treated as sourceLength - 3).

In your case, since you pass `undefined` (because `position == undefined`), it's like you omitted it

Answer (score 1):

One equal is to assign values to variables, two equals are for camparing two variables. This is the simplest way to explain it.

=  -  assigning operator
==  -  comparing operator

Answer (score 1):

`if (position == undefined){position == 0}`

This mean if your position is undefined position must be 0. Like it should be 0 but you are not defining it. Two equals is usually use to do comparution actually :  `does position is equals to 0`

However one equal mean you assign the value 0 to position.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems in your code.

```
if (to_insert == "undefined" && position == undefined){return original;}
```

Here you are checking if `to_insert` is equal to the string `"undefined"`, but not `undefined`.

```
else if (position == undefined){position == 0}
```

Writing `position == 0` will just return a boolean. So in this case, it'll return `false` (because it execute only if `position == undefined` returns true).

So it's like if in your code, you had a `false` between two lines, and you don't change the value of any variable.

```
else if (position == undefined){position = 0}
```

By writing only one `=`, you **assign** the value `0` to the variable `position`.

So, when you call the `slice()` method, the second argument is still `undefined`, so the method ignore it and just slice the string to the end.

Hope I helped you understand !

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially asking, "*What is the difference between using one equals sign (=) and using two equals signs (==)?*"

Assume we have the following initialization for both examples:

```
var pikachu_hp;
```

**One equality sign (=):**

```
pikachu_hp = 50;
```

This sets the variable, `pikachu_hp`, to have the *Number* data type with a value of **50**.

**Two equality signs (==):**

```
pikachu_hp == 60;
```

This compares the value (not data type, that's three (===) equals signs in JavaScript) of `pikachu_hp` against what is on the right hand side; in this case, that's the Number **60**. If `pikachu_hp` has a data value of **60**, the expression returns `true`. If `pikachu_hp` has a data value of anything else but **60**, the expression returns `false`. Again, I call this an "expression" because it does not *equate* to anything; it represents either a `true` or `false` value.

Comment: well, OP asked _"... would you please explain **what happens inside my wrong code**, like what causes the function to not run properly ..."_, so OP _essentially_ asked how writting `==` instead of `=` affects the next lines of code

Comment: OP's title question, which is typically the most significant part of any Stack Overlfow question, was "what would happen if you use two equals rather than only one in your execution block after an if conditional in JavaScript?" If I literally answered with emphasis on "execution block", it would be too broad; a LOT of different things could happen depending on the code. All the OP needs to understand is exactly what I explained- which provids them the ability to understand why their specific code is broken _while_ effectively answering this question for others.

Comment: @8protons Thanks alot for your answer I actually wanted to know what Santiago have explained, I explained in my question that I understand that == is a boolean that returns true or false and = is assignment, I just wanted to know how relevant it is to my code.
I understand you probably got it from my question title which poorly formatted (I'm new to stack overflow) so I'm sorry about  this.